# The simpliest way to subscribe for an observableArray in knockoutjs

Tags: google-maps, knockout.js, observable, subscribe

I have an observableArray with some markers, for example:

```
var markers = ko.observableArray([
  { 
    id: 0, 
    title: ko.observable("Marker 0"), 
    lat: ko.observable(55.31),
    lng: ko.observable(11)
  },
  {
    id: 1, 
    title: ko.observable("Marker 1"), 
    lat: ko.observable(57.20),
    lng: ko.observable(15.5)
  }
]);
```

This array is sent to some MapWidget object, that has to create google map markers for each element. It has to move markers in case lat,lng observables change, change marker's title in case title observable changes and so on.

That means in MapWidget there's some array of googlemap markers, and it should be connected with the given observableArray. What is the best and the simpliest way to connect them?

Upd. More details about MapWidget.

MapWidget is some object that has an access to some google maps map object, and it receives as an argument an observableArray with markers like that one above.

```
var MapWidget = function(markers) {
  var div = $("#map").get(0);
  this.map = new gmaps.Map(div);
  /* 
    The magic goes here:
    markers is an observableArray, we subscribe for it's changes, 
    create gmaps.marker for each new element, 
    destroy in case of destroying them from array, 
    move and rename each marker in case of corresponding changes
  */
}
```

Comment: What's "MapWidget"? You need to give more details on that...

Comment: @Kasheftin I think I understood you correctly, check out my answer. You should be able to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could subscribe to your array like this:

```
ar.subscribe(function() {
  // clean and redraw all markers
});
```

If you do that, you will receive a notification when an item is added/removed to/from the array. BUT not when an property of an item is modified.

If you want to update your google maps markers based on individual property changes in items, you could implement a [simple dirty flag mechanism](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html) and then subscribe individually to each item. Since each item has an id, which I presume is unique, you could create a map with key/value pairs being the id and the map widget.

So, given each individual item:

```
var item = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.isChanged = ko.observable(self);
  self.id = data.id;
  self.title = ko.observable(data.title);
  self.title.subscribe(function() { self.isChanged(self); self.isChanged.valueHasMutated(); });
  self.lat = ko.observable(data.lat);
  self.lat.subscribe(function() { self.isChanged(self); self.isChanged.valueHasMutated(); });
  self.lng = ko.observable(data.lng);
  self.lng.subscribe(function() { self.isChanged(self); self.isChanged.valueHasMutated(); });
}
```

And given a hypothetic map where you keep a link between your markers and the items:

```
var markersMap = [];
markersMap[0] = yourGoogleMapWidget;
```

You can then subscribe to track changes on items like this:

```
ar[0].isChanged.subscribe(function(item) {
  var myGMapMarker = markersMap[item.id()];
  // update your marker, or destroy and recreate it...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Jalayn. The first part, where we subscribe and recreate markers works correctly, but that's not what I want. The goal is only to create a new markers and destroy nonexistent, but not recreate everything with every change. http://jsfiddle.net/qtzmz/ - here I created an example of connection between observable and usual array, and it works. But look at this code! It's about thirty lines of code! How to make it easier?

Comment: 30 lines is not much! What you could do however is NOT use remove, removeAll or splice but use the destroy or destroyAll methods. Check the documentation (at the bottom of the page): http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html The difference is that the object stays in the array but is marked with a special "destroyed" property. That would save you a few lines. Would that do it for you ?

Comment: Also, the same way a "destroy" property is added, you could yourself add a "new" property when pushing a new element, and then just check for items with that property to know which ones should be created, and remove that property.

Comment: That's true. In knockout there're additional properties in binding mechanics like beforeAdd or afterRemove. I thought in subscribe there's also something similar. For example, if there's markers = observableArray(), we could write something like markers.afterAdd(function(itemThatWeHaveJustAdded) { ... }) and markers.beforeRemove(function(itemThatWeAreGoingToRemove) { ... }); It seems for me natural to have such methods, but I can't find them.

Comment: You're right, maybe you could try extending the observable array (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9014264/866172). In that answer he points to an observable dictionary (see https://github.com/jamesfoster/knockout.observableDictionary) interesting stuff!